# how to use site_url for images in wordpress with php coding

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<li><a href='#'>Core Transformation</a>
    <img alt='arrow' src=**'http://localhost/wordpress1/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/header-triangle.png'** /></li>

 <li><a href=**'#'**>LINKS</a></li>

 <li><a href=**'#'**>Contact Us</a></li>
```

How can I replace the `src` and `href` using the `site_url()` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following ways :

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/image.jpg" />

<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/image.jpg" />

<img src="<?php home_url();?>/images/image.jpg" />

<img src="<?php echo site_url();?>/images/image.jpg"/>
```

you can do it same for href

More details refer [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo site_url();?>/images/image.jpg"/>
```

or a better option would be:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/image.jpg" />
```

You can do similarly for href

Comment: still now i didn't get images for my site. I used like in both ways ,<img alt='arrow' src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/images/header-triangle.png" /></li>           <img alt='arrow' src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/header-triangle.png" /></li>

Answer (score 0):

site_url() is used to append text on url..  so if you want to navigate to your directory and fetch something you can use it like this..

site_url('/images/default.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your `src` with following way:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/yourimagename.extension" />
```

for more information about wordpress go to http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/wordpress-theme-cheat-sheet-for-beginners

that will help you more in future.

Still you getting any issues with that,then comment it.